# Nesting the same resource in multiple locations in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

So I am, like many before me, introducing the concept of "liking" items in my app. There are many different types of resources that could be liked (posts, replies, lists, actions etc.), and I am looking for the best way of structuring my routing file.

This may involve making a routes.rb file that looks something like:

```
resources lists do
  resources posts do
    resources replies do
      resources likes
    end
    resources likes
  end
  resources likes
end
```

and a LikesController that doesn't know what it is meant to be load_and_authorize - ing:

```
class LikesController < ActionController:Base

  load_and_authorize :list # only works if list_id exists in this request
  load_and_authorize :post, through: :list # only works if post_id exists in this request

  # and so on...

end
```

Are there any better ways of doing this? I had thought about just having a /likes path that everything posts to, but that means I can't use load_and_authorize, and also means it is harder to sensibly do things like Likes#index for a given list, post, reply, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a really useful question - would love to know the answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of nesting Likes inside other resources, try this:

```
scope "/lists/:list_id(/posts/:post_id(/replies/:reply_id))" do
  resources :likes
end
```

I believe that should get you a single set of LikesController routes which require a `:list_id` parameter and which optionally take a `:post_id` and a `:reply_id`. The url is pretty ugly, but I'm just trying to match the default for a quadruple-nested rails resource route. I recommend cleaning it up a bit.

Edit: It looks like this will also require some additional logic in your LikesController--like a before_filter that detects which params you've got and loads_and_authorizes only those objects. But that seems like a solvable problem to me?